# How can i run artisan commands in cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-artisan

How can i run these artisan commands in my application that is hosted in the net? Is there like a cmd in my cpanel where i can do these commands? Thanks in advance.

- php artisan clear:cache
- php artisan view:clear

Comment: How about a SSH access?

Comment: make sure to paste the URL to your site here when you are done, so we can all clear your caches

Answer (score 8):

Now in Laravel 5.8, you cannot pass **object** to **call()** func. You must pass an **array []** as second argument to call() func.

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $output = [];
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear', $output);
    dd($output);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a personalized route, and call it when you need it:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear', $output);
    dd($output->fetch());
});
```

Another solution is to access ssh to your server and to run the commands.

Comment: I tried the personalized route. How will i know if the cache was successfully cleared?

Comment: You can add an echo for your output. Look to the update of the answer.

Comment: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'BufferedOutput' not found - i get this error.

Comment: you have to add the full path for it : \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput

Answer (score 4):

Try this. You can clear all of laravel application cache hosted in shared hosting server that can not access ssh shell by the following code:

```
Route::get('/cleareverything', function () {
    $clearcache = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    echo "Cache cleared<br>";

    $clearview = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    echo "View cleared<br>";

    $clearconfig = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    echo "Config cleared<br>";

    $cleardebugbar = Artisan::call('debugbar:clear');
    echo "Debug Bar cleared<br>";
});
```

Now run `yourdoamin.com/cleareverything`

This code does not throw any error. I already used this code.

Ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Comment: Oh no !!!! totally wrong .... you just assume that the cache was successfully but you are not sure, it can also fail !!!

Comment: I already used this code in my various application and successfully clear cache and I have confirmed you that there is no error in this code

Comment: There is non sense people who give down vote without testing code. I have 3 years experience in laravel application development and I used this code in many projects.

Comment: I respect your experience, but sorry to say it, this code is wrong ! you ensure that the command was done corretly, with using echo, when you really don't know the output from it ...

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but you show cache cleared, without to know if it was really working this command or not ! Sometimes it can return an error, but with you code it will just output a success !!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple bash script called clear-cache.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP=/path/to/your/php-binary
PATH=/path/to/your-artisan-install

cd $PATH
$PHP artisan clear:cache
$PHP artisan view:clear
```

Save the script and make it executable (chmod +x clear-cache.sh). Run it through a cronjob at specific intervals and configure the cron job to email you the output of those 2 commands. This way you'll get an email, every time the cron runs the script (basically the cron will automatically issue your two commands) and the ouput will be emailed to you.

Of course there are other methods as well like creating a php script and invoke it via web